# One version of the nuget package per solution(but not the latest)

Tags: c++, nuget, native

I have a VS2013 solution with the following structure:

```
MyProject.sln
-> MyProject.vcxproj // depends on SharedCode
   -> packages.config // depends on boost 1.49
-> SharedCode.vcxproj  // library developed at another repo, i just merge sometimes or apply local fixes
   -> packages.config // alse depends on boost 1.49
```

The problem arises when someone decides to update boost used by SharedCode to 1.54. 
When I merge I need to manually check if version has changed, and manually update my dependencies.
If I run Update-Package - I will get latest version, which is inacceptable. 
Is there a way to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update-Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) has a version parameter you can use so it updates the package in all the projects to that version and not the latest version.

```
    Update-Package MyPackage -Version 1.1.0
```

Comment: It has, but anyway the problem is that I don't know when version changes in SharedCode. I need to check it manually each time I merge. It is very inconvenient and error prone.

Comment: True. There is nothing built into NuGet to automatically check for you. With NuGet you would need to check the packages.config or look at the packages in the Manage Packages dialog or use the PowerShell console. To automate this you would need to implement it yourself. You could use a custom MSBuild task or pre-build step to check the package versions are consistent.